# Why does one Hangfire background job prevent the second job from running?

Tags: .net-core, concurrency, background, job-scheduling, hangfire

Every two minutes, I have two jobs running simultaneously: ABC_Task, which takes a few seconds, and EFG_Task, which takes 1-3 minutes. When an instance of EFG_Task fails for whatever reason, it is rescheduled, and ABC_Task stops working. What am I doing incorrectly here:

```
 [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0, OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Delete)]
    [DisableConcurrentExecution(timeoutInSeconds: 10 * 60)]
    public async Task ABC_Task()
    {
        await _ng_ABC_Service.RunProcess();
    }


    [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0, OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Delete)]
    [DisableConcurrentExecution(timeoutInSeconds: 10 * 60)]
    public async Task EFG_Task()
    {
        await _EFG_Service.RunProcess();
    }
```

Comment: Hi have you tried to remove DisableConcurrentExecution ? .. it not alow to execute two job toghether (while on is running)

Comment: Hi federico , I think DisableConcurrentExecution prevents several instances of the same job from running at the same time. Both jobs are now operating, however if one of them stops working, I must log in to the dashboard and refresh it in order for the jobs to resume working.